# Why does writer.Write(msg) fail to write to os.Stdout?

Tags: go

In the code bellow, why does the `Write()` operation not work?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "bufio"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    writer := bufio.NewWriter(os.Stdout)
    //var msg []byte
    msg := []byte{104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 10}
    _, err := writer.Write(msg)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("some error")
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
Hello, playground
```

But it should be:

```
Hello, playground
hello
```

Also, I don’t want to use fmt.Println(). To be more specific, I get the data as `[]byte` type

Comment: The [documentation for bufio.Writer](https://pkg.go.dev/bufio#Writer) says *After all data has been written, the client should call the Flush method to guarantee all data has been forwarded to the underlying io.Writer.* Add the statement `defer writer.Flush()` after the writer is created or call `writer.Flush()` at the end of main.

Comment: Thank you @CeriseLimón. 
But I don’t understand the reason behind the downvote - whoever did that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Cerise Limón noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66379320/why-does-writer-writemsg-fail-to-write-to-os-stdout#comment117352280_66379320), a `writer.Write()` call merely queues up more data to be written (depending on the buffer size and the amount of data).  The actual write may happen later, or never.  In your case, since you never tell the writer to *finish any delayed write*, no write ever happens.

You'll need to invoke `writer.Flush()` (not `writer.WriterFlush()`, that's a typo of sorts).  This can return an error, if the write fails, so ideally you should check for that, not just `defer` the call and hope.  However, there's not much you can *do* about the failure, if there is one.

You can do an explicit, in-line check for error, as I did [here](https://play.golang.org/p/Z6aA1NOFHLR) for instance, or you can just defer the flush call and throw away any error.